# Rails make a gem via engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I want to make a gem which contains a view helper. I watch this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ec_aX21Byw4),
but I encounter some problems.

Here is [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/google_prettity_rails/) if you need more information.

The helper would only print `Hello world!`.

**app/helpers/google_code.rb**

```
module GoogleCode
    def self.put_code
        content_tag(:p, "Hello world!")
    end
end
```

**lib/google_prettify_rails.rb**
    require "google_prettify_rails/version"

```
module GooglePrettifyRails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    end
end
```

Then, I created another project and installed it, and I type `<%= put_code %>` in view. However, it threw this error

```
Couldn't find GooglePrettifyRailsHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/google_prettify_rails_helper.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your helper and the name of the file the helper is in do not match. Just change first line of `app/helpers/google_prettify_rails_helper.rb` to `GooglePrettifyRailsHelper`.

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful for me.